# C++ assistance with array program

Tags: c++, xcode

The program is working but I keep getting 0 and 1 when the results are printed instead of the actual numbers that I should be getting for highest, lowest, sum and average of the numbers. I know that there must something wrong with my overall code but I am not sure what it is.
This is one of the text files that goes along with this program:
-53
-22
-87
-103
-3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int getHighest(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getLowest(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getSum(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getAverage(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);

int main () {

// Variables
int numbers [ARRAY_SIZE]; 
int count = 0; // loop counter variable
string filename;


    //  Open file
    cout << "Enter input filename:";
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream inputFile(filename);   // input file stream object

    // Read numbers from file into array
    while(count <ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers[count])
        count ++;

    // Print results
    cout<<ARRAY_SIZE<<" numbers read from input file."<<endl;
    cout<<"The highest value is: "<<getHighest(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The lowest value is: "<<getLowest(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The sum of the numbers is: "<<getSum(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The average of the numbers is: "<<getAverage(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
       }

int getHighest( const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    int highest;
    highest = numbers[0];

    for(int count = 1 ; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    {
    if (numbers[count] > highest)
        highest = numbers[count];
    }
    return highest;

}

int getLowest(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        int lowest;
        lowest = numbers[0];

        for (int count = 1; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
        {
        if (numbers[count] < lowest)
            lowest = numbers[count];
        }
        return lowest;
    }

int getSum(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    sum+= numbers[count];

    return sum;
 }

int getAverage(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    return getSum(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE) / ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the file is successfully opened by `std::ifstream`? You can do so with the check `if(!inputFile.is_open()){ std::cout << "Error, file not opened\n"; return -1;}`. Its possible the filename is incorrect, or inaccessible etc.

Comment: Yes it is working. I just checked it out @Azam Bham

Comment: Where's the definition of `ARRAY_SIZE`? The code above does not compile because this is missing.

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I did not define it because the array size for each file is different so I do not know how to define it when you are given many files with different amounts of numbers @John

Comment: @coding123 If you want an array like variable but you don't know the size, then the thing to use is a vector. `vector<int> numbers;` Vectors are a basic part of the C++ standard library. You should be learning about them if you are learning C++.

Comment: @coding123 One inferior option to a vector is just to declare `ARRAY_SIZE` as big enough, Say `const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;` and just hope that you never have to read more than 1000 numbers.

Comment: @coding123 But you say that you've run your program, so you must have declared `ARRAY_SIZE` somehow. When you post code don't leave out things you aren't sure about. They are the most important things to post.

Answer (score 0):

So the main error is that you are using `ARRAY_SIZE` when you should be using `count`. `ARRAY_SIZE` is the size of your array, but the number of numbers you have read is `count`.

```
cout<<ARRAY_SIZE<<" numbers read from input file."<<endl;
cout<<"The highest value is: "<<getHighest(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
```

should be

```
cout<<count<<" numbers read from input file."<<endl;
cout<<"The highest value is: "<<getHighest(numbers,count)<<endl;
```

etc. etc.

And, although it's not wrong, it certainly would be helpful to rename the variables in your functions, so change this

```
int getHighest(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    int highest;
    highest = numbers[0];
    for (int count = 1 ; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    {
        if (numbers[count] > highest)
            highest = numbers[count];
    }
    return highest;
}
```

to this

```
int getHighest(const int numbers[], int count)
{
    int highest;
    highest = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1 ; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > highest)
            highest = numbers[i];
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how you are defining ARRAY_SIZE but if I assume that you at some point make it a constant that is = to the number of lines in the file then I was able to get it working with g++. By changing the string to a C string I was able to get ifstream to read the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int getHighest(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getLowest(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getSum(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getAverage(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);

int main () {

    //changed
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

    // Variables
    int numbers [ARRAY_SIZE];
    int count = 0; // loop counter variable
    string filename;


    //  Open file
    cout << "Enter input filename:";
    cin >> filename;

    // changed
    ifstream inputFile (filename.c_str());   // input file stream object

    // Read numbers from file into array
    while(count <ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers[count])
        count ++;

    // Print results
    cout<<ARRAY_SIZE<<" numbers read from input file."<<endl;
    cout<<"The highest value is: "<<getHighest(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The lowest value is: "<<getLowest(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The sum of the numbers is: "<<getSum(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The average of the numbers is: "<<getAverage(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
       }
```

This is the output:

```
5 numbers read from input file.
The highest value is: -3
The lowest value is: -103
The sum of the numbers is: -268
The average of the numbers is: -53
```

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I am supposed to get but I do not know what to put for array_size because the other files that were given contain more than 5 numbers @nathanael grix

Comment: The problem is that you don't know ahead of time what the array size is. You have a couple of options depending on what you are allowed to do. You could use a different data structure, like a list, that would let you fill it in without knowing the size ahead of time, get the number of lines in the file then dynamically allocate an array with the correct size, or change your program so you are calculating the high low sum and average as you go through the file.